# How can I compile a simple Swift cli program for Alpine?

Tags: swift, alpine-linux, musl

I have a simple cli written in Swift that I want to run on Alpine. I want the binary to be self-contained. How can I do that? I have tried:

- using `swift run` and `swift build` with `--static-swift-stdlib` (but that has no musl support?)
- static linking with `docker run -v "$PWD:/sources" -w /sources --platform linux/amd64 swift:latest swiftc -emit-executable -static-executable -O main.swift testit`, but then the executable `testit` when running it on Alpine, says it is `Unable to obtain Swift runtime path Aborted`.

The code of the program:

```
// The Swift Programming Language
// https://docs.swift.org/swift-book
func getSecret() -> String {
    let CharArr: [Character] = ["T", "h", "i", "s", " ", "a", " ", "s", "e", "c", "r", "e", "t"] 

    let newStr = String(CharArr) 
    return newStr
}
if(CommandLine.arguments.count == 2){
    if (CommandLine.arguments[1] == "spoil"){
        print(getSecret())
    } else {
        if (CommandLine.arguments[1] == getSecret()){
            print("This is correct! Congrats!");
        }else{
            print("This is incorrect. Try again");
        }
    }
} else if (CommandLine.arguments.count==1) {
    print("Welcome to the wrongsecrets Swift binary which hides a secret.");
    print("Use args spoil or a string to guess the password.");
} else {
    print("Too many arguments supplied.");
}
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: Does adding `--static-swift-stdlib` work?  Also you can test what libraries the executable will use, _before_ transferring it to the target machine, using `ldd`.

Comment: using swift run/build/package i can use that flag. Using swiftc directly i cannot.
The LDD output:
 ldd wrongsecrets-swift 
 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7f64213d0000)
 libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x7f6420c28000)
 libm.so.6 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7f64213d0000)
 libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x7f64213b7000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7f64213d0000)
Error loading shared library ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: No such file or directory (needed by wrongsecrets-swift)

Comment: So no swift `.so` files; which is good, but why couldn't it load `ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`???  Are you cross-compiling?

Comment: Compiling from the Swift Docker in MacOS

Comment: OK so the docker will be running arm64 and that file won't be there.  Does the executable work on the target machine now?

Comment: Nope :( . After extensive checks and chats with Swift developers it turns out that it will not work at all. Swift has no musl support yet :( .